# SAS, drop rows where values are numeric

Tags: excel, sas

I have rows from a Excel-file where some columns contains numeric values. I want to drop all rows that have columns with numeric values. One row I want to drop is for example:

```
User ID City State Country Age 
4969          30   4970    Missing value
```

Is there any easy function for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting a row with a condition is fairly straightforward.  You can use ANYALPHA to identify columns with non-numeric fields.

```
data want;
  set have;
  if not (anyalpha(state)) then delete;
run;
```

Comment: You'd probably want to set up an array to loop through each variable